# What is the significance of the 'postscript' in Lamentations?

Tags: lamentations

[image]

What is the meaning and translation of the 'postscript' at the end of the book of Lamentations as is recorded in the Stuttgartensia?

Comment: My Hebrew is not good enough to provide a translation but these postscripts usually provide a summary of the numbers of verses and sections in the text. See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135953/what-are-the-19-sections-of-the-book-of-psalms-in-the-biblia-hebraica-stuttgar) for a similar example.

Comment: Thanks Dan. That certainly makes sense given the meticulousness of the scribes in transcribing the text.

Comment: I figured out that the Hebrew קנד with a small dot over each letter is translated as 154 the number of verses in the book. I believe the beginning couple of lines read something like: "sum of judgement[s] of book (154)." The last two lines with the number 16 superscripted to the left of תחת is a bit of a mystery. Like the example pointed out to me by Dan, do these lines somehow refer to sections?